# xmlstarlet finds my html invalid

Tags: html, xmlstarlet

I'm using xmlstarlet to query the source code of the following webpage, as a test: http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/

This is the command I'm using:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//h2" mfw.html
```

It returns a bunch of errors like this:

```
mfw.html:81.8: Premature end of data in tag body line 12
</html>
```

It appears xmlstarlet doesn't validate the document. When I run `xmlstarlet val mfw.html`, this is the output:

`mfw.html - invalid`

I observed similar behavior with a bunch of other HTML documents. Is my understanding of XML/HTML validity at fault here or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: HTML isn't XML.

Comment: @npostavs grrreat, thank you!